# Python higher order functions: how do I avoid repeating arguments?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, higher-order-functions, functools

I have a higher order function with required argument `required`, function `func`, and arguments for `func` `*args`. However, `func` *may* take `required` as an argument.

```py
def higher_order_func(required, func, *args):
    func(*args) # This MAY take `required`
    do_something_with(required)
```

This works fine but is not pythonic when I supply some `func` which takes `required` as an argument.

```py
def my_func(required):
    do_something()
```

Now when calling with the higher order function, I must repeat the argument!

```py
higher_order_func(required, my_func, required)
```

This does not seem neat to me, and I'd much rather have `higher_order_func` only require an argument once.

**Solution 1**

Use `functools.partial` and supply the partial function to `higher_order_func`.

```py
from functools import partial
higher_order_func(required, partial(func, required))
```

This doesn't really solve the problem, `required` is still written out twice.

**Solution 2**

Check if `'required'` is in `func`'s argument names, and call it conditionally.

```py
def higher_order_func(required, func, *args):
    if 'required' in func.__code__.co_varnames:
        func(required, *args)
    else:
        func(*args)
    do_something_with(required)
```

I can now call as desired:

```py
higher_order_func(required, my_func)
```

Neater, but seems hacky.

**Is there a more pythonic way to achieve this?**

Comment: Can you show a more concrete example of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It seems suspicious that you are trying to pass two different kinds of functions (one taking `required` and the other not taking it) to the same higher-order function. Possibly there should be two different higher-order functions for each case.

Comment: The important question to ask yourself is, "How shall the caller specify that `required` must be passed to `func`?" It may be easiest to just pass `required` twice. The only problem with your Solution 2 is that it requires passed functions to always have the same name for the `required` parameter. I don't like the idea of functions being so heavily coupled with how they're called.

Comment: The example doesn't really have repeated arguments. If two arguments happen to have the same name, that needn't imply that they have the same meaning. It's purely coincidental that a single variable named `required` can be used to pass the same value to two different arguments, so it seems dubious that the function should be designed to allow for that possibility.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I believe the full use case confuses the question. `higher_order_func` runs a stage of a data pipeline, with `required` being a set of IDs. I am intentionally not using a pipelining framework as I am doing the run on a small number of IDs incrementally, and wish to keep open a SQLAlchemy database session while running the stages one by one so that I can rollback in case the run fails. Regular runs of these functions do use standard pipelining. Hence, I've simplified the code to elucidate exactly what I'm trying to solve.